# How to write xml file from IDataReader in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, ado.net

If I have an IDataReader, how would i go about constructing a xml writer to output to xml.  Would It require a custom stream or writer?  I'm trying to write to an xml file but I have access to an IDataReader.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to build a class that mimics the data in the `IDataReader` and simply serialize it to XML. Let's say the data in the data reader was `Field1, Field2, Field3`, the class would look like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
    public string Field3;
}
```

Of course the data types could differ. Now, all we need to do is read the data into the class, that might look something like this:

```
var list = new List<Data>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var o = new Data();
    o.Field1 = reader["Field1"];
    o.Field2 = reader["Field2"];
    o.Field3 = reader["Field3"];
    list.Add(o);
}

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Data>));

using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
{
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, list);
}
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I want, but I want to output it in the schema that would be output by the database if I call FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA('TestXsdSchema').

Basically I want the xml file to match the default schema of the database, which will be dynamic.